# R xts how to union two xts/zoo with overlapped time scope and a main and a seconday

Tags: r, xts

I have two xts/zoo, one is main, the other is seconday. I want to union them by rows. The two xts/zoo may have dupliacated index with different values.
If index duplicated, the main rows should be remained.
Such as

```
mainXts
2019-02-26    4
2019-02-27   90
2019-02-28    6
2019-03-01    7
2019-03-02    8
2019-03-03    9
2019-03-04   10

secondaryXts
2019-02-23    1
2019-02-24    2
2019-02-25    3
2019-02-26    4
2019-02-27    5
2019-02-28    6
```

The result should be

```
2019-02-23    1
2019-02-24    2
2019-02-25    3
2019-02-26    4
2019-02-27   90
2019-02-28    6
2019-03-01    7
2019-03-02    8
2019-03-03    9
2019-03-04   10
```

Is there simple way to do the union?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you would call it simple, but this does the trick. First merge both of the xts objects with the main one first, check the column names inside the out object and use these inside the ifelse. In the ifelse, replace the NA's with the value from the second column and afterwards we get rid of the column you do not need.

```
out <- merge(mainxts, secondxts)
out$mainxts <- ifelse(is.na(out$mainxts), out$secondxts, out$mainxts)
out$secondxts <- NULL

out
           mainxts
2019-02-23       1
2019-02-24       2
2019-02-25       3
2019-02-26       4
2019-02-27      90
2019-02-28       6
2019-03-01       7
2019-03-02       8
2019-03-03       9
2019-03-04      10
```

data:

```
mainxts <- structure(c(4L, 90L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), index = structure(c(1551139200, 
1551225600, 1551312000, 1551398400, 1551484800, 1551571200, 1551657600
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .CLASS = "integer")

secondxts <- structure(1:6, .Dim = c(6L, 1L), index = structure(c(1550880000, 
1550966400, 1551052800, 1551139200, 1551225600, 1551312000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .CLASS = "integer")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And further, if  the name and number of the colums  does not been determined, how to change the code?   Thanks.

Comment: Name of columns are not important, a self written function can take care of that. But multiple undetermined columns can be an issue because you need to know which column is needed to fill the na's. So if you could create an example of this and the rule which column needs to be filled based on which column from the second xts and add that to your question I or someone else can have look.